# Just installed Debian - Having trouble connecting to wireless network

Tags: debian, wpa-supplicant

I know this question has been asked before but none of the solutions are working for me. I just installed Debian and I'm relatively new to Linux. I'm running Debian 7.4 (Wheezy) with Gnome desktop. At the moment, I'm connected to the Internet via Ethernet cable and I'm having trouble connecting to a wireless network. My network uses WPA2. I've tried connecting with wpa_supplicant but so far that hasn't worked. I don't know where I'm messing up. It would be great if someone with experience in this could help me out. Thanks.

Note: Just let me know what information you need (for example, the output of a certain command) and I will supply you with that.

Edit: I followed https://askubuntu.com/questions/138472/how-do-i-connect-to-a-wpa-wifi-network-using-the-command-line and when I execute

```
wpa_supplicant -B -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -Dwext && dhclient wlan0
```

I get the following error:

```
Could not read interface wlan0 flags: No such device
WEXT: Could not set interface 'wlan0' UP
wlan0: Failed to initialize driver interface
```

Comment: Show the output of `ip link`.  This will list your network devices. It may be that your WiFi device isn't called `wlan0` - it should start with a `w` though.